# How to export primary keys on data-dump?

Tags: symfony1, foreign-keys, doctrine, primary-key, data-dump

When I export my database with doctrine:data-dump, I encounter 2 problems:
* the primary keys are not exported
* instead of foreign keys columns correct name, it uses the name of the foreign table.

For example, here are my tables:

```
# schema.yml
Planet:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: planet
  columns:
    planet_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      sequence: planet_planet_id
    solarsystem_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
  # some columns...
  relations:
    Solarsystem:
      local: solarsystem_id
      foreign: solarsystem_id
      type: one
  # other relations...

Solarsystem:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: solarsystem
  columns:
    solarsystem_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      sequence: solarsystem_solarsystem_id
    # other columns...
  relations:
    Planet:
      local: solarsystem_id
      foreign: solarsystem_id
      type: many
    # other relations
```

When I dump, I find things like that in data.yml:

```
Planet_1:
  Solarsystem: _1
```

When I data-load that, it doesn't work (Invalid row key specified: (solarsystem) _1, referred to in (planet) Planet_1). I have to fix manually like this:

```
Planet_1:
  solarsystem_id: 1
  planet_id: 1
```

For the moment, I'm fixing the data.yml manually, but it begins to become a pain with all the records I'm accumulating...

Note: I'm using Symfony 1.4, Doctrine, postgreSQL, NetBeans, Windows. Feel free to ask information you would judge useful.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out this article entitled "Never Trust doctrine:data-dump": http://www.thomaskeller.biz/blog/2010/01/29/never-trust-doctrinedata-dump/

With that in mind, you may instead prefer checking out pg_dump:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html#BACKUP-DUMP

This dump is postgreSQL level, and as such is not likely to care about -- or stumble over -- your Doctrine schema.